# Nearest Neighbour using KDtree

Tags: java, data-structures

I know how to construct a kd tree .But the problem that i am facing is how to find nearest neighbour using KD Tree.I have searched on google but not able to find code for finding nearest neighbour,though algos are given . But I am facing difficulty in converting that algo into code because of Language.

Can you please provide me understandable code for NNSearch in java?

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudocode that assumes the target point is not stored in the tree. (If it is, just add logic to ignore it):

```
nearest_point = NULL
nearest_distance = INFINITE;
target_point = <set to the target point>

void nn_search(KD_NODE node) {
  FLOAT d = node->point.distance_to(target_point);
  if (d < nearest_distance) {
    nearest_distance = d;
    nearest_point = node->point;
  }
  BOX left_bb = node->left.bounding_box();
  BOX right_bb = node->right.bounding_box();
  if (left_bb.contains(target)) {
    search_children(node->left, node->right, right_bb);
  else { // right_bb must contain target
    search_children(node->right, node->left, left_bb);
  }
}

void search_children(KD_NODE a, KD_NODE b, BOX b_bb) {
  nn_search(a);
  // This condition makes the search expected O(log n) time rather than O(n).
  // Skip searching the other child unless it might improve the answer.
  if (b_bb.contains_point_closer_than(target, nearest_distance)) {
    nn_search(b);
  }
}
```

After this has run, `nearest_point` contains the nearest point to the target.  Note that it's simple to compute the bounding boxes as parameters of `nn_search` rather than storing them inside the nodes, which this code appears to do.  In production code you'd want to do that to save the space of 4 floats per node.  I've omitted the parameters for simplicity.

The predicate `contains_point_closer_than` returns true if there exists *any* point in the bounding box that's closer to the target than the given distance. Happily it's enough to consider only one point in the box.  E.g if the current node splits the search space into left and right halves at `X`, then you only need to consider the point `(X, Y_target)` and its distance to the target.  That distance is just `abs(X - X_target)`! I'll let you convince yourself of this without further discussion

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. But Can you tell about bounding_box function.How to define it?

Comment: If I am not mistaken bounding box is like circle or rectangle .But no idea how to define it

Answer (score 0):

I know two Java kd-tree implementations that support kNN search, [here](https://www.savarese.com/software/libssrckdtree-j/) and [here](http://home.wlu.edu/~levys/software/kd/). Theirs performance appears to be roughly equivalent.